# Delay after didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have a tableview with custom cells, when I tap on one of my cells it shows me the next viewcontroller as it should be, but there is a delay which sometimes goes up to 5 seconds.

How can I get rid of the delay?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let person = persons[indexPath.row]

    var personViewController: PersonViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PersonViewController") as PersonViewController

    personViewController.name = person.name
    personViewController.imageName = person.image

    self.presentViewController(personViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

PersonViewController

```
import UIKit

class PersonViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var personImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var overlayImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

var name: String?
var imageName: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.personImage.image = UIImage(named: imageName!)
    self.overlayImage.image = UIImage(named: "image_overlay.png") //this is a filter
    self.nameLabel.text = imageName
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: Could you please include your `PersonViewController` initializer code? It's likely the `PersonViewController` is causing the delay.

Comment: @Armin I've added my PersonViewController code

Comment: Can you remove first only one image then both images and check if delay is still there?

Comment: @zelb i removed one and the delay is still there

Answer (score 27):

I have the same problem and it seems that this is a bug of iOS. 
Solved with the following solution.

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 
    Int64(0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), 
    dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
        self.presentViewController(personViewController, animated: true,completion: nil)
    }
```

Swift3 version:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.presentViewController(personViewController, animated: true,completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Stupid bug! Grrrrrr... wasted my time with this. Thank you!

Comment: Weil, stupid bug, why doesn't Apple fix this bug after few past years?

Comment: No need for `asyncAfter(deadline..`. `DispatchQueue.main.async {...` works just as well.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks

Comment: Mid 2019 and still the same problem. And thank God still the same solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you will call the method

`[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];`

before Push ViewController or Other Operation. Like

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // 1. manual call this method to deSelect Other Cell
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    // 2. than do other operation
    PushViewController Or Some Animation ....
}
```

that`s solve my problem . when i custom transition viewController for Model Style

Comment: This works for Swift 3 iOS 10.2 when presenting UIAlertController or UIViewControllers: Swift 3: tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)

Comment: However, if you have other functions that depend on indexPath via tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row, you will no longer have the indexPath available unless you save it

Answer (score 0):

You are loading two images and instantiating a view controller from the storyboard after someone taps on a cell. This involves a heavy process, and can take time depending on how complicated your view controller is, and how big those images are.

Now you could either move your image loading code to `viewDidAppear()` or maybe load the images asynchronously and then assign them.

---

Another way could be to use `imageWithContentsOfFile:` to load the images. Apparently this method is faster and [uses less memory](http://www.jorambarrez.be/blog/2012/04/19/ios-imagenamed-vs-imagewithcontentsoffile/).

```
NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image_name" ofType:@"jpg"];

UIImage *currentImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:file];
```

Comment: My images are all less than 200KB, I just tried moving them to  `viewDidAppear()` and it indeed had no delay, just the images load about 1sec later which i prefer not to. I'll look up on how to do the asynchronous loading and tell you how that's going.

Comment: 200KB is not small when it comes to displaying images. Loading those images is going to take that time, unless you load them differently! Try `imageWithContentsOfFile:` for example. Apparently it uses far less memory, and doesn't cache the image, so it should be faster.

Comment: Updated my answer with an example.